# Error when trying to pass '==' overload to std::map comparator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, comparator, non-static

I'm trying to pass an overload of a custom class as a comparator of an `std::map`.

Here's some code and the error to help you help me :

Here is Position.hpp

```
#ifndef POSITION_HPP_
# define POSITION_HPP_

class   Position
{
public:
  int   _x;
  int   _y;

  Position(){}
  Position(int x, int y)
  {
    _x = x;
    _y = y;
  }

  void  setPosition(Position &newpos)
  {
    _x = newpos._x;
    _y = newpos._y;
  }

  int   getX()
  {
    return _x;
  }

  int   getY()

     return _y;
  }
  void  setX(int x)
  {
    _x = x;
  }
  void  setY(int y)
  {
    _y = y;
  }

  struct cmpIsSame{
    inline bool operator==(const Position& pos)
    {
      if (pos._x == _x && pos._y == _y)
        return true;
      return false;
    }
  };

  inline Position&      operator=(const Position& pos)
  {
    _x = pos._x;
    _y = pos._y;
    return *this;
  }
};

#endif
```

And here is the map declaration in GameEngine.hh

```
private:
  std::map<Position, Case, Position::cmpIsSame> _cases;
```

And here is the error:

```
Position.hpp: In member function ‘bool Position::cmpIsSame::operator==(const Position&)’:
Position.hpp:17:7: error: invalid use of non-static data member ‘Position::_x’
   int _x;
       ^
Position.hpp:52:21: error: from this location
       if (pos._x == _x && pos._y == _y)
                     ^
Position.hpp:18:7: error: invalid use of non-static data member ‘Position::_y’
   int _y;
       ^
Position.hpp:52:37: error: from this location
       if (pos._x == _x && pos._y == _y)
                                     ^
```

Any help would be a pleasure?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to just overload `operator== (const Position&, const Position&)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**As to the error**

In the implementation of the `operator==` you attempt to access members `_x` etc. of the enclosing class. You don't have access to them there. Embedding a class in a class is a namespace issue, not a member access issue.

It would be easier to just provide a free function or a functor that offers the comparison.

**As to the comparison of keys in `map`**

The definition of the key comparison for [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) is [`std::less`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less) which by default calls `operator<`. It may be easier to just implement an overloaded `operator<` for the key you use.

```
bool operator<(const Position& lhs, const Position rhs&) {
  // your implementation of "less" here...
}
```

**As to the implementation of `less`**

This is really up to you and manner in which you use it in the application. But as a first off approximation (also to try get the code up and going), consider using the distance ([pythagorean theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Pythagorean_theorem)) of the point to the origin (probably 0,0).

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to use either functional object or a static function.
But in any case your approach is wrong because the comparator shall satisfy the strict weak ordering principle that correcponds to operator <.

From the C++ Standard (23.2.4 Associative containers)

> 3 The phrase “equivalence of keys” means the equivalence relation
>   imposed by the comparison and **not the operator== on keys**. That is,
>   two keys k1 and k2 are considered to be equivalent if for the
>   comparison object comp, comp(k1, k2) == false && comp(k2, k1) ==
>   false. For any two keys k1 and k2 in the same container, calling
>   comp(k1, k2) shall always return the same value.